# Is there somewhere I can download the entire source code for an application?

Tags: android

I'm currently learning how to build applications for android online, following tutorials on youtube and Udemy.

I want an entire Android Studio app package to tinker with to help me learn how to code properly.  In the same way I learned about fixing cars by taking one apart and putting it back together, I was hoping somebody could point me in the direction of a place where I could get an app and mess around with it.

Ideally I'd like a fitness app but I'd take anything except games at the moment.

HYelp anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find tons of samples and examples on github. For an example checkout this fitness app.
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit

Please use those sample codes in compliance with the License.